# Include page only when radio button selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I'm completely new to Javascript and jquery, but I have a page, and 3 forms. The forms are in an external file. I need that when I select Radio Button 1, Form 1 appears, Radio Button 2, Form 2 appears, etc.

Thank you.

Tom.

Comment: And what have you tried? What problems you encounter?

Comment: I simply don't know how to do it...

Comment: you could include all your forms and hide them. Displaying only when selected. [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: That I can't do, because the forms conflict when they are previously loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ajax like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="ajax-form"></div>
<input class="radio-1" type="radio">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.radio-1').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'form-1.html',
        complete: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-form').html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('.radio-2').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'form-2.html',
        complete: function(data) {
            $('#ajax-form').html(data);
        }
    });
});

...
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I'm not sure how to implement this. Just the iquery in <script> anything else needed? T

Comment: Include jQuery in your <head> and then add this to the bottom of your <body> tag, then have all of your forms loaded into different files (form-1.html, form-2.html, etc.) in the root of your site.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little jsfiddle demo to show you how you would generally approach this.

```
var $button = $(".button"),
    $paragraph = $(".sometext");

$button.click(function (event) {
    // do something when ".a_button" is clicked.
    $paragraph.toggle();
    // there are many functions like .toggle
    // Take a look at .show and .hide, .slide, .animate and .fade
})
```

[Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/NVb9Q/)